# 100 React forwardRef components containing img trigger an error when one img src request fails

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a page where I render about a 100 imgs inside forwardRef components. After adding an onError listener, I found that every single img triggers the callback, even though only one img src request returned an error. Why is that happening and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please update your question with the code for a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and its linked resources for more info.